# Is it flood DDOS attack?

Tags: security, ddos

I'm a regular user of your website but I never asked a question. I hope, it's a good way. For some weeks, I have special DDoS attacks on a website. I don't know what kind of attack they are and how is it possible to launch them. The question is not how to block them, I know this, but what kind of attack it is and how is it possible. I think it's flood DDOS attack, but how this one?

For some weeks, 3 times, I had on my website thousands and thousands gets (+/- 10,000/min, during 30 minutes, to make down my server), such as :

- index.php/q=99999, all queries are different and existing on the website;
- all IP are the same per attack (only one IP per attack, and the 3 IP used for each of these attacks are in the same segment xxx.xxx.xxx... From a same host in another country, which doesn't have link or competition or anything with my site.
- the user-agents are different (+/- 40 different agents per attack, never two times the same successively, but all of them same time.)

I don't think that the IP sources are really the attackers, because, it's little stupid to use all the same IP for such attack. But I think that the hackers want to make me think that the attacks are really coming from these IP.
But, if these IP sources are not real, how is it possible to launch such attack, with +/- 40 different agents, coming from the same IP in same time. Is-it easy to do that? does it need big systems? A single hacker could do that? Or such services are cheap and existing on the net?....

I can block such attacks but I try to understand the goal, the meaning of them and how they do that. To block only is not enough. I need to understand. If you cannot help, maybe advise me where I could find the information.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

It does sound like an attack alright. It's not hard to pull off, nor set up. These kinds of attacks are usually done via computer farm or a zombie horde, and as such it's fairly easy to set up, and as a result to that, it's a service offered online.

People do this because they can or because of a personal and/or business vendetta.

I could write about this topic for hours, but none of it wouldn't have been said before. So allow me to forward you to some further reading on the topic.

***For a quick and dirty overview:***
Tom's hardware [entry](http://www.tomsguide.com/us/ddos-attack-definition,news-18079.html) on the topic is also a nice, condensed, straight to the point write up, which I've found useful in the past.

***A more detailed, yet broad overview of DDoS attacks and protection:***
Wikipedia's [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) on Distributed Denial of Service attacks is extremely well written and updated. I suggest you start there.

***If you're serious about defending yourself/ educating yourself:*** CISCO's [article](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&ved=0CFgQFjAG&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cisco.com%2Fweb%2Fabout%2Fsecurity%2Fintelligence%2Fguide_ddos_defense.html&ei=38bcVJHhCJbtasriguAK&usg=AFQjCNH1h2-JCmrNmvSc0Wo6VyjWNyScYw&sig2=dTzCU8CoqUxOdVdRUcaQ0A&bvm=bv.85761416,d.d2s) on how to defend yourself against DDoS. It's extremely detailed and long and useful. I've come back to it several times over the years for help on the topic -- both academically and professionally.

*Good luck!*

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm (almost) sure it's vendetta, like you said, because, they attacked 3 times in some weeks. But These IP are not blacklisted everywhere. The same IP source and 40 agents surprise me. Is it possible to have something like this [hacker]->[computers horde] --> [same fake IP/rooting...] --> My site? Thx.

Comment: The IP addresses can be spoofed, in fact, they most likely are. The other option is that they're using a local farm, but even then, they should spoof the IP addresses or go through a proxy. To answer your question in short -- yes.

Comment: Thks. Ok for attacks from PC farm (because only one IP source and +/- 40 user agents). Ok for IP spoofing/proxy IP, but the biggest problem in these attacks are the spoofed IP themselves. They are very secured IP in a country which has one of the best IT security (IL). Tha't not very believable or usual. 3 attacks with the same seg of secured spoofed IP in 4 weeks is not only one. That's my point right now. Maybe we could talk in MP because some site's members don't like my topic. It's not typically coding problem, but a DDos attack can occure to any "good" webmaster. Whe have to understand.